# Make collapsable panel close when another one is opened

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using jQuery to slideToggle some content when the button is clicked. Here's my HTML:

```
 <div class="seasons">
    <div class="container text-center">
     <div class="row margin-top-medium">
        <div class="col-md-12 1">

     <div class="season hvr-shrink">12×01 Chi Cerca Trova</div>
            <div class="content">
             <div class="hvr-shrink">12×01 Chi Cerca Trova</div>
            </div>
    </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">

    <div class="season hvr-shrink">12×02 Il Mini Peter</div>
              <div class="content">
             <div class="hvr-shrink">12×01 Chi Cerca Trova</div>
            </div>
    </div>
         <div class="col-md-12">

    <a href="#"><div class="season hvr-shrink">12×03 Un Quagmire per Quagmire</div></a>
    </div>
    </div> 
    </div>
```

And this is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
$(".season").click(function(e){
    $(this).next().slideToggle("fast");

});

});
```

Panels open as they should but when one is opened, and I click to open another panel, the previous one doesn't close. Is there any jQuery code for that?
Thanks everyone for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using .hide() function when document is ready. You can use same function, when user click a different panel header.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".content").hide();
    $(".season").click(function(e){
      var thiz = $(this);     
      if(!thiz.hasClass("opened")){
        $(".content").hide();
        thiz.next().slideToggle("fast");
        $(".season").removeClass("opened");
        thiz.addClass("opened");
      }
    });
});
```

You can see a demo: http://codepen.io/ogzhncrt/pen/zGQqwx